# SQL : How to sum a column based on the range of value in another column in SQL?

Tags: sql

Below is the data available to me:

```
rate     Fee
 0.12    48,599 
 0.29    80,718 
 0.37    94,110 
 0.44    75,289 
 0.62    79,236 
 0.85    99,210
```

Now I need to summarize in following way:

```
Rate_classification               Fee
Low Rate (0 -to- 0.25)            48,599 
Moderate rate (0.25 -to- 0.75)    329,353 
High rate (0.75 -to- 1.00)        99,210
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use a case expression to classify the rates. GROUP BY.

Comment: select * from table where 1=1 group by ...? how to exactly put rate_classification values in column 1 of output like "low_rate", "high_rate" etc.

Comment: In which rate classification should be included the values  0.25 and 0.75 ..?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan : Either is fine, I'll add the border condition later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `case` expression in a derived table to classify the rates. `GROUP BY` its result:

```
select rate_class, sum(fee)
from
(
    select case when rate < 0.25 then 'low rate'
                when rate < 0.75 then 'medium rate'
                else 'high rate'
           end as rate_class,
           Fee
    from tablename
) dt
group by rate_class
```

Comment: @JNevill, According to ANSI SQL yes, but most dbms don't have that restriction.

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know that restriction.

Comment: ANSI SQL only allows columns in the GROUP BY. However, I don't mind, then you only specify the case expression once - which makes the code easier to maintain.

Comment: @Jarlh :Works perfectly well. Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

you can try below way

```
      select case when rate>=0 and rate<.25 then 'Low_Rate'
        case when rate>=.25 and rate<.75 then 'Moderate'
         else 'High' end as Rate_classification,
         sum(fee)           
    from your_table group by Rate_classification
```

Comment: @ErayBalkanli dbms where support alias in group by will work fine

Comment: Like MySQL and perhaps SQLite?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution including cte structure for this question, respecting to jarlh's answer.

```
;with cte (Rateclass,rate,fee) as (

   select Rateclass = (case when rate >=0.0 and rate < 0.25 then LowRate
                            when rate >=0.25 and rate < 0.75 then ModerateRate
                            when rate >=0.75 and rate < 1.0 then HighRate end),
          rate,
          fee
   from table

)
select Rateclass, sum(fee)
from cte
group by Rateclass
```